# Why success is not being returned in my PHP WSDL (Zf2)

Tags: php, wsdl, zend-framework2

I used these two resources as launching pad for my creation of a WSDL endpoint server.

```
https://odan.github.io/2017/11/20/implementing-a-soap-api-with-php-7.html
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e_7jDqN2A-Y&t=799s
```

By combining these two I was able to come up with a hybrid system that works. My issue that I am trying resolve right now is getting a response back from the api.php/endpoint server.

In the odan git example, it worked to the letter. But once I made changes to the code that requires objects. I started getting errors.

```
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object
```

Here is a portion of the server code.

---

```
class wenoError
{
    public $response = "Sucess";

    public static function authenticate($header_params)
    {
        if($header_params->username == 'WEX' && $header_params->password == 'WEX1') return true;
        else throw new SOAPFault('Wrong user/pass combination', 601);
    }

    /**
    * @param string $payload
    * @return string $delivery
    */
    public function receivePayload($payload)
    {

        $xml = base64_decode($payload);

        $fileName = 'message-'.rand().'.xml'; 
        $file = file_put_contents('messages/'.$fileName, $xml);
        $xml2json = simplexml_load_string($xml);
        $jsonOut = json_encode($xml2json); 
        $arrayJson = json_decode($jsonOut, TRUE);
        //$seeArray = print_r($arrayJson, true);
        //file_put_contents('messages/converted-'.$fileName.'.json', $arrayJson['Header']['MessageID']);
        $response = "Success";
        return $response;

    }

}
    $serverUrl = "https://localhost/WenoErrors/api.php";
    $options = [
        'uri' => $serverUrl,
    ];
    $server = new Zend\Soap\Server('wsdl', $options);

    if (isset($_GET['wsdl'])) {
    $soapAutoDiscover = new \Zend\Soap\AutoDiscover(new \Zend\Soap\Wsdl\ComplexTypeStrategy\ArrayOfTypeSequence());
    $soapAutoDiscover->setBindingStyle(array('style' => 'document'));
    $soapAutoDiscover->setOperationBodyStyle(array('use' => 'literal'));
    $soapAutoDiscover->setClass('wenoError');
    $soapAutoDiscover->setUri($serverUrl);

    header("Content-Type: text/xml");
    echo $soapAutoDiscover->generate()->toXml();
    } else {
    $soap = new \Zend\Soap\Server($serverUrl . '?wsdl');
    $soap->setObject(new \Zend\Soap\Server\DocumentLiteralWrapper(new wenoError()));
    $soap->handle();
    }
```

---

What I don't understand is the error message of $response being a non-object. According to the PHP manual https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

The property is set correctly at the top of the class, the property is declared and a value us set.

What went wrong?

UPDATE:

Adding the client code.

```
$client = new Zend\Soap\Client('https://localhost/WenoErrors/api.php?wsdl');
$delivery = $client->call('receivePayload',[['payload' => $message]]);
```

Dumping client yields:

```
C:\eRxGateway\www\apa\WenoErrors\clientapi.php:55:
  object(client)[3]
   public 'delivery' => null
```

UPDATE:

What finally worked for me was this change.

First change:

```
$server = new Zend\Soap\Server('wsdl', $options);

$server = new Zend\Soap\Server(null, $options);
```

Comment: `$this->response` is a string, not an object.

Comment: I'm not seeing enough information in your post to give a definitive answer but @delboy1978uk is probably correct if your implementation code is expecting the return of `receivePayload` to be an object. The key is the line number -- the "PHP Notice" also includes a file and line number that you have not provided here.

Comment: What I have posted is the entire endpoint code. I already know that $this->response is not an object and I have tried several different ways to create an object but none have worked. I was hoping someone would not post the obvious that should be in the writeup. So, if anyone can expound on why it's not an object according to PHP rules it should be an object. That would be most beneficial.

Comment: You need to look for parts of your code where `$response` is being referenced as an object. You don't provide an exact error message that includes the code throwing the error, so I can only guess that the problem lies in code not included in the question. Where are you calling `receivePayload()`? What are you doing with the return value? If you're trying to do something like `returnVal->something()`, that will definitely throw an error, as `$response` is only ever set to a string. And [strings are not objects](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: I got the error message to go away by adding $respons = "Success". But when I dump the class it still returns  'delivery' => null.

Comment: It's not clear what is your current issue. `What I don't understand is the error message of $response being a non-object.` How do you came to this conclusion? Are you sure the problem is with the `$response`? The `PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object` is happening on server side? Can you provide the entire error you are receiving with the entire stack-trace?

Comment: @DiogoSgrillo The error was cleared by $response = 'Success'. The issue that I still have remaining is that 'Success' is not being returned.

Comment: So, you should update your question to describe better your issue. `Success is not being returned` - What is the result of `var_dump($delivery)` (on the client)? There is anything on your server log?

Comment: @DiogoSgrillo I have updated the question and added the var_dump from the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine for me. Though, I am getting a different result then yours as below:

```
$client = new Zend\Soap\Client('http://localhost/test/api.php?wsdl');
$message = ' -> Hello World'; 
$delivery = $client->call('receivePayload',[['payload' => $message]]);
var_dump($delivery);

object(stdClass)#4 (1) {
  ["receivePayloadResult"]=>
  string(7) "Success"
}
```

> Step 1

Please try to remove all the '/tmp/wsdl-****' files from your **/tmp** directory. You seem to be on windows, so instead of **/tmp** it might be something else like **C:\Windows\Temp**. You can easily find which directory by going into your **php.ini** file and looking for the below directive.

```
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"
```

> Step 2

Also, for developing and testing purposes always put the below ini directive at the start of your client php file, which in your case is ***clientapi.php*** file.

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);
```

You shouldn't be required to put this directive at the start of the server(api.php) file, but you can if the above still does not work for you.

Comment: Thank you for the concise response. I have done all that you ask and yes, I am developing on a windows server. What did you do to receive the receivePayloadResult? I am dumping $client = new client; var_dump($client).